# Cant run tensorflow on ubuntu 16.04 using python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, ros

I have installed the tensorflow using pip in python 2.7.

When I try to test the tensorflow in python, all I get is this message:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ python
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  1 2018, 23:32:55) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/anto/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/anto/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/home/anto/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "/home/anto/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 113
    class DescriptorBase(metaclass=DescriptorMetaclass):
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I am currently running on:

- ubuntu 16.04
- ros1 kinematic
- python 2.7
- keras 2.6
- tensorflow 1.14
- protobuf 3.18.0

Comment: What version of protobuf do you have installed?

Comment: using pip show,
 3.18.0

Answer (score 1):

i have tried re-install a protobuf version of python 2.7 and tensorflow 1.x
this is all i get to solve this problem

- encontered error in Tensorflow 1.8 Request you to uninstall by using
  `pip uninstall protobuf` and try installing `pip install protobuf==3.8`
- encontered error in Tensorflow 1.14 Request you to uninstall by using
  `pip uninstall protobuf` and try installing `pip install protobuf==3.9`

it works for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).